# If someone is sued in Singapore, can he transfer all his assets to europe?

Tags: contract-law, search-and-seizure, litigation

Just wondering what if someone know he's about to get sued say in a modern country like Singapore. he transfers all his assets (such as cash) overseas to another modern country like Germany. Then he loses the lawsuit. Can the local court seize his assets overseas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No, a Singaporean court can’t enforce a judgement in Germany

But a German court will enforce the judgement of a Singaporean court in Germany. It does add additional time and cost for the successful party but most of that can be recovered.